# OpenGL : how to avoid jerks in scrolling / animations

Tags: android, delphi, opengl-es

I m under `delphi`, under `android`, and it look like an `openGL` problem. I have problem to obtain **smooth scrolling**. i always have **Jerks** :( To render the frame we do like this :

```
will running do begin // << main loop

  doSomething // << calculate for example position of controls regarding velocity

  executeAllTimerProcedure;

  eglMakeCurrent(..)
  paintEverything // << paint all texture, this took around 5 ms
  eglSwapBuffers(...) // << stuck waiting the vsync signal

end;
```

The problem is that `eglSwapBuffers` wait for `vsync signal`. as the vsync signal is fired every 16.6 ms (60fps) the main loop is blocking at the step `eglSwapBuffers`. This can cause some jerk in the scrolling if the calculation made in dosomething are delayed. Also all timer are delayed.

i try to set `eglSwapInterval(eglGetCurrentDisplay, 0);` and this make eglSwapBuffers non blocking but now (and i don't know why) the jerks are even worse :(

So what i can do to make my scrolling /animation very smooth without any jerks ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: 60Hz is more than enough to have smooth scrolling. Your problem may be the interpretation of smooth not being the same as high frequency. Have you tried techniques such as blur? You may get better performance if updating next frame (doSomething and execAllTimer) between paintEverything and eglSwapBuffers. Remember to glFlush after paintEverything.