# How it's possible that calling repaint from a background thread can slow down the animation?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

under android with delphi, I have a background thread. in this background thread i call a procedure in synchronize that just do a repaint:

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    repaint;
  end);
```

to resume you the delphi source code, under android repaint simply put a bool to true saying to the main looper to repaint the form on next loop :

```
procedure TPlatformAndroid.InvalidateWindowRect(const AForm: TCommonCustomForm; R: TRectF);
begin
  TAndroidWindowHandle(AForm.Handle).NeedsUpdate := True;
end;
```

I have also a mousemove event on my form in with i catch the mouse move and where i also call repaint

```
procedure TMyFrame.FrameMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  VPos := Y; 
  repaint;    
end;
```

**What i absolutely not understand now,** is why this repaint (in the background thread) **cause some jerks in the animation** if (and only if) **i also move at the same time my finger on the screen** (if i do not move the finger then i don't have jerks)

How this could be possible? because the repaint simply put to true something that was already to true via the mousemove (or vice versa). how this can delay sometime by more than 100 ms the call to the onpaint of my frame (producing jerks). Removing the onpaint from the background thread remove also the jerks ... no idea what could be wrong

NOTE:

if in `TPlatformAndroid.InternalProcessMessages` if i replace

```
if TWindowManager.Current.RenderIfNeeds then
    HasEvents := True
```

by

```
TWindowManager.Current.RenderImmediately;
HasEvents := True;
```

then the lag disappears a lot (but not completely)

Comment: So you call `Synchronize` over and over from inside the thread? Do you have any sort of delay between calls? Or they're just back to back? If there's no delay, then your thread is essentially blocking the main thread from actually being able to do its work. Has nothing to do with setting a boolean, and everything to do with blocking the main thread with `Synchronize`. It is in fact the way to make the thread communicate with the main one, but if you keep calling it back to back, you're not giving the main thread a chance to do its job. At minimum put a delay but I don't know why you need this.

Comment: As a test, what happens if you comment out `repaint` from inside your `Synchronize`? Do you still observe a lag?

Comment: let say yes, in this example, over and over. No it's can't block the mainthread, because the main loop (TPlatformAndroid.InternalProcessMessages) do: processUImessage, Render, processTimerEvent, and processsynchronize. as render take in any case around 16ms (opengl vsync) then our synchronize (that do nothing exept puting a bool to true) will be executing every 16 ms (min) so no raisin to impact the animation

Comment: @JerryDodge : no if i comment the repaint and leave the synchronize everything work fine, no more lag ... i m totally lost !

Comment: Your question says nothing about OpenGL. Sounds like a pretty graphic intensive app in that case. I still have difficulty in understanding why you want to even do such a thing. If it works fine without calling `repaint` here, then why would you need this thread at all? Is this the only thing it does?

Comment: @JerryDodge: to say everything, the thread is downloading an image, then resizing it and when everything is done and ready, in synchronize make it available to the mainthread and in case the user was not moving the screen call repaint to refresh everything. the animation it's similar to an vertical scroll box with velocity. but the the instruction onpaint in the synchronize add some lag :( and this only when user is also touching the screen

Comment: off course i can remove the onpaint (or do it if mousedown is false), but i want to understand why :( i m crazy to not understand something so trivial, can't understand what is wrong

Comment: "in synchronize make it available to the mainthread" I don't see anything like that in your question either. That sounds like your problem. How are you making this image available to the main thread exactly if not in this `Synchronize` call? Are you calling `Synchronize` again somewhere else? Or is your main thread directly pulling this image from the thread object?

Comment: In any case, there are numerous things which surfaced later on in the comments, which weren't a part of your question. You seem to assume that I know everything about your project, I don't. "Removing the onpaint from the background thread remove also the jerks" How do you even have an `OnPaint` in a background thread? Is this even possible? `OnPaint` of what, your form? A custom control?

Comment: no jerry, i don't want to make the sample over complicated (this why i make a resume), in the sync i just do: items[x].img := theprocessedimg; repaint; that all but as i say the error is coming because of the use of repaint with the mouse event

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? I just went to test your scenario, and in Firemonkey, `TForm` doesn't even have a `Repaint` procedure. Even the 3D form.

Comment: ooh thanks Jerry! wait i will try to make a workable example for you. i m under Tframe, this why i have repaint (but in android doesn't matter as their is no partial draw, repaint = form.invalidate = redraw the full form)

Comment: @JerryDodge. unfortunatly to make a workable demo it's will be a little over complicate :( anyway i appreciate a lot that you try to help ... right now i think that the problem is connected to timer / opengl vsync that is not respected / ui message. for exemple if i replace in TPlatformAndroid.InternalProcessMessages TWindowManager.Current.RenderIfNeeds by TWindowManager.Current.RenderImmediately then i don't have anymore any lags (i still have but much more less).

Comment: You are asking a lot of pretty unclear questions, and none of them is about actual problem you are trying to solve. It seems all of them are about this question [OpenGL : how to avoid jerks in scrolling / animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964645/opengl-how-to-avoid-jerks-in-scrolling-animations) where you didn't provided proper [mcve]. Please visit [help] and read more about how this site works, or you will have rough ride.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i find out why.

in delphi the problem is that, even if repaint is a trivial operation with set a flag to true, the following operation that will actually render the form is not trivial and in any case (even if the form didn't change) it's will take 16 ms (the vsync signal penalty). my problem is also connected to ui event because when their is ui event, delphi fire every timer every 1 ms instead of every 10 ms

so you can understand that if i call the repaint at a bad time (say for exemple the nanosecond before normally the timer must be fired), then we will have 16ms delay to wait and then when the timer will fire, it's will be too late, we will have already one frame dropped (in fact not but last paint did nothing), and then we will have lag :(

also it's because of this bug: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18982